# שב between the tekiot?

Tags: prayer-book, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

In some *machzorim* the word "שב" appears in between the sets of *tekiot* before *musaf* of Rosh HaShanah.

See e.g. [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Sefard%2C_Sounding_of_the_Shofar%2C_Blessings_and_Sounding_of_the_Shofar.33?lang=bi):

> תקיעה. שברים. תרועה. תקיעה.‏
>
> תקיעה. שברים. תרועה. תקיעה.‏
>
> תקיעה. שברים. תרועה. תקיעה.‏
>
> שב

What is it doing here? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means sit down after hearing the blasts, that the preceding instruction was to stand up for:

> גם השומעים נכון שיעמדו
>
> It is proper that also those who hear it should stand

Comment: But then the next line tells them to stand up and confess their sins silently... why are they told to sit down and immediately stand up?

Comment: @JoelK I don't know, that's a good point and possibly a different question. My guess would be something like, a person should _rise_ to confess. Therefore it's best to start from a seated position and stand up. This is not my minhag so I can't comment (we sit for the blasts in sefardi shuls). Maybe it's just referring to the shaliach tzibbur? The seating might be a relic from the times before this minhag developed to say the vidui here?

Comment: tweaked the translation to make it a little clearer. please feel free to revert if you disagree

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what the [aruch hashulchan](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan,_Orach_Chaim_590.5) writes in OC 590:5

> ועוד נראה לי: כיון דקשה לתוקע לתקוע שלשים
> קולות בהמשך אחד, ובהכרח שינוח קצת, כמו שהמנהג אצלינו לנוח קצת בין תשר"ת לתש"ת ובין תש"ת לתר"ת, ואם כן ממילא אי אפשר לחשוב האחרונה הקודמת לראשונה העתידה מפני ההפסק. ואף שבדיעבד יצא, שהרי אפילו שמע תשע תקיעות בתשע שעות – יצא, מכל מקום לכתחלה אין הדבר מהודר.

שב means break. In short we want to differentiate between the different sets, so we pause, i.e. שב.